# qt3 to qt4 include file change

Tags: qt, qt4

I face a problem when tansfer an qt3 code to qt4 code. I found the code the "

```
#include <qdict.h>
```

and using two Qt class 
named QDict and QDictIterator
"
but Qt4 doesn't have the qdict.h file

How to find counterparts in QT4?

Answer (score 1):

Is it `QDict` that you are talking about?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/porting4.html#qdict-t